# Получить график с Google Analtytics

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, диаграммы

Помогите, пожалуйста, мне нужно получить график данных с Google Analytics (GA). Дело в том, что нужно получить данные по определенным событиям, которые созданы были в GA, а не общие данные. Кажется это возможно сделать при помощи одного JavaScript и воспользоваться Google Charts для отображения.

Инет перерыл.. API гугла тоже.. %))
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Подскажу вам некоторые ссылки для изучения:

1. [Core Reporting API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries?hl=ru)
2. [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
3. [Google Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/)

Надеюсь, что вы соберете это всё воедино.

Comment: Бывал я кончено же везде.. и график или данные получаю именно, касаемо всего сайта.. а мне нужны данные исходя из созданных в GA событий.. таких примеров, с сожалению не нашел..